# Making a Game how would i assign an image(sprite) to a specific object to have certain behaviours

Tags: java, user-interface, object

For example a certain image on the screen how would correspond to an object  so it would have certain values like how much damage or health it has

Would you put a bufferedImage in the constructor of that object or am i thinking about the problem in the wrong way an this is handled in a GUI class

thanks in advance

Comment: Any futher details i can go into more depth if i was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably an "opinion based" question that the mods won't like, but my advice would be to keep your game objects and their graphical representation separate. Your objects contain things like their health or the damage, and when you update your game world you only work with these, decrementing the health when the character takes damage, etc.

Then in a separate phase in your game loop you're going to render the sprites. You choose how to render them based on the data in your objects. But I would keep the "business" code and the "graphics" code separate, and not mix them inside the same classes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Use layered architecture and use the right type of classes in the right layers : entity, controller, boundary.